# Confusion about run time and libraries in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to use an MQTT library in elixir known as Tortoise. Whenever I use `iex -S mix` I can get the sending of messages to work. However when I use `mix start` to begin my start task the program will not work. I'm get an `unknown registry: Tortoise.Registry` error.

I can start the supervisor for Tortoise without error, it is when I try starting a child process for that process with `Tortoise.Supervisor.start_child` that I get the error.

```
defmodule Mqtt.Begin do
require Tortoise
def start do

opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Mqtt.Begin]
  {:ok, pid} = Tortoise.Supervisor.start_link(opts)

      {:ok, _} =
    Tortoise.Supervisor.start_child(Mqtt.Begin, [
      client_id: :a,
      handler: {Mqtt.Handler, [name: :a]},
      server: {Tortoise.Transport.Tcp, host: 'localhost', port: 1883},
      subscriptions: [{"share/share-group/bar", 0}] ])
```

When using extern libraries in elixir is the entire library created with deps.compile? Or do I need to do something further?

Comment: I believe you should add `:tortoise` to the list of applications in your `mix.exs` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this is because of erlang code loading principals 
When you start your application using `iex -S mix` erlang starts it into `interactive mode` and automatically loads all modules.

`mix start` (you should call `mix run`) seems to start your application in `embedded mode`
In embedded mode, code is loaded at start-up according to a boot script.

http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/code_loading.html#code-loading

To make it work you have to add `:tortoise` into your `application` list in `mix.exs` :

```
def application do
    [
      extra_applications: [:logger, :ssl, :tortoise],
      mod: {Your.App, []}
    ]
end
```